# How to align text box with legend box in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to place text at the top left of my figure, and then have the legend next to it at the same vertical height. The following doesn't do what I would expect:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
ax.plot([0, 1,2,3],[2, 5,8,33], label='legend')
plt.legend(loc=[0.5, 1.2], fontsize=20)
fig.text(x=0, y=1.2, s="Text", fontsize=20)
```

[image]

It seems like the positioning using `text()` and `legend()` are inconsistent? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

`Figure.text` is in figure co-ordinates, so it is being placed outside the figure.  `plt.legend` is in axes co-ordinates.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
ax.plot([0, 1,2,3],[2, 5,8,33], label='legend')
plt.legend(loc=[0.5, 1.2], fontsize=20)
fig.text(x=0, y=1.2, s="Text", fontsize=20, transform=ax.transAxes)
```

works.  (or `plt.text(x=0, y=1.2, s="Text", fontsize=20, transform=ax.transAxes)`)

[image]

Comment: ...or `fig.legend()` - then both `legend` and `text` are placed in figure coordinates.